# When $f$ holomorphic, $|f(z)-f(0)-f'(0)z|\leq 3c|z|^2$

Tags: complex-analysis

$f$ be a holomorphic function on $A:=\{z; |z|\leq 1\}$, and $c:=\max {|f(z)|}$. Then, for all $z\in A$, $|f(z)-f(0)-f'(0)z|\leq 3c|z|^2$

By using Laurent expansion and Cauchy's formula I can prove if $|z|$ small, but I can't prove in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let
$$g(z)=\frac{f(z)-f(0)-f'(0)z}{z^2}.$$
Then $g$ is holomorphic on $A$. When $|z|=1$,
$$|g(z)|\le c+|f(0)|+|f'(0)|\tag{*}$$
and so by the maximum modulus theorem (*) holds on $A$.
It's clear that $|f(0)|\le c$, so to complete the proof, all you
need to prove is that $|f'(0)|\le c$.